# deleting values from a list in python three

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I want write a function that deletes even numbers from a list (for example xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6]) and then returns the the remaining list. Help needed. Thank you
note: I cant use any built in functions like remove sort etc, but only the delete statement.

Comment: And? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, since there is no `delete` statement, I guess you're going to fail the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to return the remaining list, you should not delete but filter instead:

```
[v for v in xs if v % 2 == 1]
```

This creates a list with all the odd numbers:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [v for v in xs if v % 2 == 1]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way doesn't work:

```
for index, value in enumerate(xs):
    if not value % 2:
        del xs[index]
```

Or, worse, it happens to work in this particular case, but only because you got very lucky (and your teacher may even be counting on you to fall into this trap).

Why? Well, when you `del i[0]`, that shifts everything else down. So when you next check `i[1]`, that's not the original `i[1]`, but the original `i[2]`. You never check, and therefore can't ever delete, the original `i[1]`!

This is explained in a big grey note in the documentation for [`for`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).*

---

The best solution to this is, as Martijn Pieters says, to not delete in the first place.

If you don't care about mutating the original list (if no other object has a reference to the same list, and your teacher isn't fond of trick questions, you don't care), just create and return a new list, as in his answer. Even if you *do* need to mutate the original list, `xs[:] = [v for v in xs if v % 2 == 1]` will do that just as well as deleting in-place.

But if you must delete in-place for some reason (and it sounds like that *might* be a requirement of your assignment), the easiest way is to work backward from the end:

```
for index, value in list(enumerate(xs))[::-1]:
    if not value % 2:
        del xs[index]
```

Since deleting a value from a list only shifts down the ones after it, going through the list in reverse order means we never get lost and skip over an element we wanted to test.

---

* The explanation reads like something from Python 1.x; now that the iterator protocol is public, they don't really need to talk about keeping internal counters in some unspecified place…

Answer (score 0):

```
xs=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

not_even = []
for i in xs:
    if i%2 != 0:
        not_even.append(i)

print not_even
#output: [1, 3, 5]
```

You can also do it using list comprehensions:

```
[i for i in xs if i%2 != 0]
```

Comment: This is just a much more long-winded version of Martijn Pieters' answer, without the explanation.